# How to specify what named service instance to inject into a controller with StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-core

Microsoft Unity DI offers a feature where you can register multiple objects for the same interface and give them a name. Then in your constructor you can use an attribute with the argument to specify by name which object you want to inject.

I am wondering how to achieve this same functionality using StructureMap.

Example:

```
container
.RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>("MappingEngineOne", new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(MappingEngineOneConfiguration)))
.RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>("MappingEngineTwo", new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(MappingEngineTwoConfiguration)))

....

public class MyServiceAgent {
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mapper;
    public MyServiceAgent([Dependency("MappingEngineOne")] IMappingEngine mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
}

public class MyOtherServiceAgent {
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mapper;
    public MyOtherServiceAgent ([Dependency("MappingEngineTwo")] IMappingEngine mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This is a bad practice. Your classes should not know about which implementations they should receive.

Comment: We have multiple services that need an IMappingEngine instance instantiated with a certain configuration. How would you go about solving this?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649735/dynamic-selection-of-interface-implementation-using-ioc).